# How to implement Unity like internal call with mono

Tags: mono, unity-game-engine

C# side code

```
[WrapperlessIcall]

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]

private extern void INTERNAL_set_rotation(ref Quaternion value);
```

How to expose this method from C++ to mono

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You need to call `mono_add_internal_call`:

```
mono_add_internal_call ("YourClass::INTERNAL_set_rotation", yourclass_INTERNAL_set_rotation);
```

There is some documentation here: http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono#Exposing_C_code_to_the_CIL_universe

And here is a code sample: https://github.com/mono/moon/blob/8d8ece884382d653d215b0da5bf633079566d816/src/deployment.cpp#L579